# Create a list without specifying the exact amount of items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

Is it possible to create lists without specifying how many items are going to be in it?

At the start of my code, I create all the lists I want to populate by using:

```
lot_list = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
lowest_list = ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]
highest_list = ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]
```

These lists can store 7 items so, if I want to store 8 items, I am having to add a new ,“0” to each list each time if I want the code to add an 8th item later.

Is there a way to not have to specify the list size at the start? Or some kind of dynamic list where it doesn’t matter?

Comment: Lists are dynamic, you can `.append()` to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers already mention that lists in python are dynamic, so you can specify an empty list and append to it.

Also, [other operations are supported](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), such as insert `list.insert(i, x)` (inserts an element at a given position), which allows you place an element anywhere in the array, not just at the end.

Answer (score 3):

In python when you define list you don't need to define size, or a type. And if you like you can mix and match. (i.e. list with int, string, and complex data types)

```
list_a=[]

for i in range(1,100):
    list_a.append(i)
```

Comment: "unlike other languages (i.e. JAVA)"  you are assuming that java has no dynamic list?

Comment: @RoadRunner yes, I meant array and not list. and so I removed that statment.

Answer (score 1):

Python lists are dynamic, and can hold any number of items. For example, if this was your code:

```
mylist = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for i in range(7):
    mylist[i] = i ** 2
```

You could modify it to look like this:

```
mylist = []

for i in range(7):
    mylist.append(i ** 2)
```

In fact, you could do `for i in range(1000)` and it would be fine. A way to shorten the above is a list comprehension:

```
mylist = [i ** 2 for i in range(7)]
```

which would do the same.